# Reset/Render again element in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Their is option in polymer to reset element/ custom element to the original state. Like render the element again?

I want all the inner variables values to delete and that the element will look the same as I load the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see to ways:

First one is just to write 'reset' method which resets all vars so that bound ui gets to the initial state.

The second one is to remove the element with Polymer.dom(parent).removeChild and then create new one of same type with document.createElement and put it at old element's place with Polymer.dom(parent).appendChild/insertBefore.

I'd choose first one - seems to be more testable and confined to the lement.

Comment: Ok, I new that I thought that their is a default reset function. cause if I use someone else element writing reset method can be difficult.